# Where is this function welldefined?

Tags: functions

Can this function
$$\left(\frac{3a^2-a}{15+3a}\right)\left(\frac{25-a^2}{9a^2-6a+1}\right)\left(\frac{3}{a}-9\right)$$

be simplified to
$$\frac{(5-a)(1-3a)}{(3a+1)}$$

and if that is true a can't be $\frac13$ or $0$  or $-5$  is this correct or in another case what is wrong?

Comment: The simplification does not look right. Also (though not everybody agrees) one should determine where defined *before* simplification.

Comment: To determine whether the function is defined at, for example, $a=0$, ask yourself what your calculator would do if you fed in $a=0$. Mine would scream a big $\Large E$, and refuse to do anything more. It turns out that at $a=0$, you have a *removable* singularity (if you simplify, the problem disappears). But still, the function *as written* is bad at $a=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplification is not correct.

On correct simplification you will end up with $(a-5)$, with conditions that :

$a$ is not equal to ${-5,0,\dfrac{1}{3}}$

*Simplification:*

$$\dfrac{a(3a-1)}{3(5+a)}\dfrac{(5+a)(5-a)}{(3a-1)(3a-1)}\dfrac{3(1-3a)}{a}$$
$$=(a-5)$$

Answer (score 1):

It is not well defined for $$a=0,\frac{1}{3},-5$$
The function simplifies to-$$a-5$$